# Read query to SQLite DB hangs while using Python3 multiprocessing

Tags: python-3.x, sqlite, multiprocessing

I have a test list of 10,000 IDs and this is what I have to do:

1. For every test ID, calculate rank by comparing with other IDs i.e. people from same company
2. Check if the rank for this test ID is above 'normal' by a) calculating ranks (same as step 1) of 1000 randomly selected IDs b) comparing these 1000 ranks with the rank of test ID
3. Do this (step 1 and 2) for 10,000 test IDs with data from 10 different months.

To store the master data of 14000 IDs and observation for 10 months I am using sqlite as it makes querying and ranking easier and faster.

To reduce the run time, I am using 'multiprocessing' and parallelize calculations on number of months i.e. ranks calculated for different months on different cores. This works well for less number of test IDs (<=2000) or less random ranks (>=200) but if I calculate ranks for all 10 months in parallel and using 1000 as number of random ranks for each ID than the script freezes after a few hours. No error is provided. I believe SQLite is the culprit and need your help to figure out the issue.

Here is my code:

```
nproc = 10 ## Number of cores
randNum = 1000 ## Number of random ranks for each ID

def main():
    '''
    This will go through every specified column one by one, and for each entry
    a rank of entry will be computed which is comapred with ranks of randomly selected 1000 entries from same column
    '''
    ## Read master file with 14000 rows X 20 cols, each row pertains to an ID/ID,
    ## first 9 columns have info related to ID and last 10 have observed values from 10 diff. months
    resList = List with 14000 entries Eg. [(123,"ABC",.....),(234,"DEF",........)....14000n]

    ## Read test file, for which ranks to be calculated. Contains 10,000 IDs/IDs and their names
    global testIDList ## for p-value calculation
    testIDList = List with 1000 entries Eg. [(123,"ABC"),(234,"DEF")..10,000n]

    ## Create identifier SET - Used for random selection of IDs
    global idSET ## USed in rankCalcTest
    idSET = SET OF ALL IDs FROM MASTER FILE

    global trackTableName,coordsDB,chrLimit  ## Globals for all other functions

    ## Specify column numbers in master file that have values for each ID from different months
    trackList = [10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20] ## Columns in file with 14000 rows each. 
    ### Parallel
    allTrackPvals = PPResults(rankCalcTest,trackList)

    DO SOME PROCESSING
    SCRIPT ENDS

def rankCalcTest(col):
    '''
    Calculates ranks for test IDs using column/month specified by 'main()' function 
    '''
    DB = '%s_%s.db' % (coordsDB.split('.')[0],col) ## New DB for every column/month - Because current function is paralleized so every core works on a column/month
    conn = sqlite3.connect(DB)

    trackPvals = [] ## Temporary list that will hold ranks for single column/month
    tableCols = [col] ## Column with observed values from an month, that will be used to generate column-specific ranks

    ## Make sqlite3 table for current track
    trackTableName = 'track_%s' % (col) ## Here a table is created containing all IDs and observations from specifc column
    trackTableName = tableMaker(trackTableName,annoDict,resList,tableCols,conn) ## This modules not included in example, as it works well -uses SQLite
    chrLimit = chrLimits(trackTableName,conn) ## This module not included in examples as it works well - uses SQLite

    for ent in testIDList: ## Total 10,000 entries

        ## Generate Relative Rank for ID/ of interest
        mainID = ent[0] ## ID number
        mainRank = rankGenerator(mainID,trackTableName,chrLimit,conn) ## See below for function

        randomIDs = randomSelect(idSET,randNum)
        randomRanks = []
        for randID in randomIDs:
            randomRank = rankGenerator(randID,trackTableName,chrLimit,conn)
            randomRanks.append(randomRank)

        ### Some calculation
        probRR = DO SOME CALCULATION
        trackPvals.append(round(probRR,5))

    conn.close()
    return trackPvals

def rankGenerator(ID,trackTableName,chrLimit,conn):
    '''
    Generate a rank for each ID provided by 'rankCalcTest' function
    '''
    print ('\nRank is being calculated for ID:%s' % (ID))

    IDCoord = aDict[ID] ## Get required info to construct the read query
    company = IDCoord[0]
    intervalIDs = [] ## List to hold all the IDs in an interval
    rank = 0 ##Initialize

    cur = conn.cursor()

    print ('ID class 0')
    cur.execute("SELECT ID,hours FROM %s WHERE chr = '%s' AND start between %s and %s ORDER BY hours desc" % (trackTableName,comapny))
    intIDs = cur.fetchall()
    intervalIDs.extend(intIDs) ## There is one ore query in certain cases, removed for brewity of code

    Rank = SOME CALCULATION
    print('Relative Rank for %s: %s'% (ID,str(weigRelativeRank)))
    return Rank


def PPResults(module,alist):
    npool = Pool(int(nproc))    
    res = npool.map_async(module, alist)
    results = (res.get())
    return results
```

The script freezes in 'rankGenerator' function:

```
Rank is being calculated for ID:1423187_at
Rank is being calculated for ID:1452528_a_at

Coordinates found for:1423187_at - 8,111940709,111952915
Coordinates found for:1452528_a_at - 19,43612500,43614912
ID class 0
```

As, the run was performed in parallel its hard to say at which line script is freezing but seems like the query in 'rankGenerator' is the freezing point. Is it related to locks in SQLite?

Sorry for large code. It is actually a very trimmed version that took me 3 hrs to prepare. I hope to get some help.

AK

Comment: What happens if you do the calculations serially, without multiprocessing?

Comment: @Joel: Never tested in serial mode with more than 2000 test IDs and 100 random ranks as it is going to take many days to test on just one 'month' data. But it's nice suggestion so I have started the analysis in serial. Any thing unsual in 'rankGenerator' function that might cause DB locking or query waits?

Comment: @Joel: Serial run on one 'month' works pretty well without errors. Now I am puzzled completely about why analysis gets stuck in parallel. Any suggestions?

Comment: I have the similar problem as yours: multiprocessing with sqlite3, /proc/pid/stat display this pid as "D (disk sleep)" for all night. This job should take a few hours to complete. Deadlock somewhere?